# MySQL count distinct Customers from Orders by period

Tags: mysql, date, count, group-by, distinct

I have this stuff

```
mysql> explain Order;
+------------------------+-------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type              | Null | Key | Default   | Extra          |
+------------------------+-------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11) unsigned  | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment |
| date                   | timestamp         | NO   |     | NULL      |                |
| customer               | int(11) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL      |                |
| address                | int(11) unsigned  | NO   |     | NULL      |                |
+------------------------+-------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
```

And I need to count all active customers month by month in one year, for example:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%m/%Y') as period,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(customer)) as total

FROM
  Order

WHERE
  YEAR(`date`) = '2012'

GROUP BY
  period
```

But GROUP BY with DISTINCT are not working well and this SQL are returning a lot of results for the same period

**@edit** Will result this

```
07/2012 1
07/2012 1
06/2012 1
09/2012 1
12/2012 769
06/2012 1
07/2012 1
07/2012 1
06/2012 1
06/2012 1
10/2012 1
... a lot of results with 1 as total
```

And I'm expecting this

```
01/2012 329
02/2012 279
03/2012 229
04/2012 379
05/2012 411
06/2012 152
07/2012 277
08/2012 411
09/2012 468
10/2012 501
11/2012 488
12/2012 593
```

Comment: What do you mean _not working well_?  Can you post some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Are returning this:
07/2012 1
07/2012 1
06/2012 1
09/2012 1
12/2012 769
06/2012 1
07/2012 1
07/2012 1
06/2012 1
06/2012 1
10/2012 1

Comment: Please edit your OP and show some sample data and the desired result don't place it in the comments.

Comment: See this demo, the code appears to be working -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee519/2

Comment: my date it's a timestamp... can be the problem?

Comment: That should not matter -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac7fb/1

Comment: I don't understand with the same schema, with your example data I'm getting different result im my server with 5.5.30 the same version.

Comment: Can you edit your OP with some sample data from the table?  Not the result of the query.

Comment: @bluefeet I miss a typo and omitted another important information in the production version I have one column with the same name "period" -_- when I recreate your fiddle example in an empty db worked! Thank you

Comment: Create a anwser with your fiddle example than I will accept as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query should work if the date is a datetime or a timestamp:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`,'%m/%Y') as period,
  COUNT(distinct customer) as total
FROM Orders
WHERE YEAR(`date`) = 2012
GROUP BY period
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee519/2)